# ActiveMQ access to previously published data on subscription

Tags: c#, activemq-classic

We're using ActiveMQ locally to transfer data between 5 processes that turn simultaneously.

I have some data I need to send to a process, both at runtime (which works perfectly fine), but also a default value on start. Thing is it is published when the process starts, it just doesn't read because it wasn't subscribed to the topic at the time the data was sent.

I have multiple solutions : I could delay the first publishing for a moment so that the process has time to launch (which doesn't seem very appealing) ; or is there a way to send all stored previously non-treated messages to some process that just subscribed ?

I'm coding in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with ActiveMQ, but other message system usually have an option which marks the subscription as persistent, which means that; after the first subscription; the message queue itself checks if a certain message is delivered to that system and retries with a timeout. In this scenario you need to start the receiver at least 1 time.

If this is not an option and you want to plug in receiver afterwards, you might want to consider a setup of your messages which allows you to retrieve the full state, i.e. if you send `total-messages` instead of `differential- messages`.

After a little google, I came upon this definition `durable subscribers`, I hope this helps:

See:

http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-durable-queues-and-topics-work.html

and

http://activemq.apache.org/manage-durable-subscribers.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those out and come back to you

Comment: @Saryk Did you found your answer?

Comment: I ended up sending a message to the main process when the second one had started, and wait for the reception of that message in the main process to transfer everything I needed.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using C# client i don't konw if this is supported

```
topic = new ActiveMQTopic("TEST.Topic?consumer.retroactive=true");
```

http://activemq.apache.org/retroactive-consumer.html

So, another solution is to configure this behavior on the broker side by adding that to the activemq.xml and restart :

> The subscription recovery policy allows you to go back in time when
>   you subscribe to a topic.

```
<destinationPolicy>
  <policyMap>
    <policyEntries>
      <policyEntry topic=">" >
        <subscriptionRecoveryPolicy>
          <timedSubscriptionRecoveryPolicy recoverDuration="10000" />
          <fixedCountSubscriptionRecoveryPolicy maximumSize="10000" />
        </subscriptionRecoveryPolicy>
      </policyEntry>
    </policyEntries>
  </policyMap>
</destinationPolicy>
```

http://activemq.apache.org/subscription-recovery-policy.html

Answer (score 0):

I went around the issue by sending a message from each process when they're launched back to the main one, and then only sending the info I needed to send.